# Координаты вершин гексагона из d3js

Tags: d3.js

Я новичок в d3js. Рисую гексогональную сетку из [этого примера](https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2013/07/self-organizing-maps-creating-hexagonal)

Рисуется отлично. Но мне для моей задачи нужны координаты вершин гексагонов. МНе удалось вытащить вот такой массив:

> "M55.028105984729244,0m0,-31.770491803278688l27.514052992364622,15.88524590163934l3.552713678800501e-15,31.770491803278684l-27.514052992364622,15.885245901639351l-27.514052992364622,-15.88524590163933l-1.7763568394002505e-14,-31.77049180327868z"

Где

> M55.028105984729244,0m0,-31.770491803278688

скорее всего координаты центра. Где то там есть еще радиус. Но почему 5 пар точек и что такое

> "-31.77049180327868z"?

Comment: Возьмите листик, ручку, отношение синуса к прямоугольному треугольнику - и посчитайте 6 координат. https://ege-study.ru/ru/ege/materialy/matematika/sinus/

Comment: function pointy_hex_corner(center, size, i):
    var angle_deg = 60 * i - 30°
    var angle_rad = PI / 180 * angle_deg
    return Point(center.x + size * cos(angle_rad),
                 center.y + size * sin(angle_rad))

Comment: Пример был взят отсюда:https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates